# Sagepay release payments

Tags: php, payment, opayo

I have payments going into SagePay as deferred using SagePay Direct. When ready, I would like to be able to release these payments from my system rather than logging into MySagePay to do it.

I have spoken to SagePay support who have told me that the Reporting and Admin API can do this but I can find no method that refers to actually releasing a payment.

Does anyone know a way that this is possible and if there are any PHP wrappers for the Reporting and Admin API to save me writing my own.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Daryll, what does "deferred" mean in this context?

Comment: Deferred as in SagePay deferred. The payment is put on hold and not taken until the merchant releases it. See this link for the official description [http://www.sagepay.com/help/faq/what_is_deferred_and_release](http://www.sagepay.com/help/faq/what_is_deferred_and_release)

Comment: OK, as I expected, StackOverflow's "deferred" tag means something very different. I will remove it.

Comment: It's not the Reporting and Admin API that enables you to release deferred payments. It is the Sage Pay Shared (between Server and Direct) API that does that. Details here: https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/8691/download-document/Server_and_Direct_Shared_Protocol_Guidelines_180314.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide for remotely releasing payments can be found in the Server/ Direct Shared Protocols guide.  This can be accessed via the following link;

http://www.sagepay.com/help/userguides/76186

If you have any further issues please let me know.

Thanks,

Shawn